# how to efficiently write Python object as file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I had a `model` dict() contains a total of `16.777.215` data.
but when I saved that model to `.JSON` files, that took `1.21 GB (1,308,622,848 bytes)`.

Is there any method to efficiently save this object to a file with less size?

And is there any method to load that file to my model dict()?

because I had to save `16.777.215 * 64 * 64 * 64` more.

That will take all my space.

Comment: what kind of data are you saving to file?

Comment: in model dict().
some string as keys; and hash as value

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample of your data?

Comment: {"000": "2ac9a6746aca543af8dff39894cfe8173afba21eb01c6fae33d52947222855ef", "100": "ad57366865126e55649ecb23ae1d48887544976efea46a48eb5d85a6eeb4d306", "200": "27badc983df1780b60c2b3fa9d3a19a00e46aac798451f0febdca52920faaddf", "300": "983bd614bb5afece5ab3b6023f71147cd7b6bc2314f9d27af7422541c6558389", "400": "26d228663f13a88592a12d16cf9587caab0388b262d6d9f126ed62f9333aca94"}

Comment: You could zip the json.

Comment: it that possible to zip the json when writing ??
or maybe I can devide the json. at some pointers i can make that json to .part and compress it to zip :D
good idea thanks !